# How to let user input TABLE name in sqlite3, python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, create-table

I need to prompt a user to create a student table, check if a table with such a name exists in the database, and if not create it.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('School')
print ("Database has been created")

def create_table():
 TableName = input("Enter table name: ")
 tb_create ="""CREATE TABLE , (TableName,) (ID INT PRIMARY KEY,title VARCHAR(10), forename VARCHAR(20), 
 surname VARCHAR(20))"""
 tb_exists ="SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name= ?", (TableName,)
 if not conn.execute(tb_exists).fetchone():
   conn.execute(tb_create)
   print ("Table created successfully")
 else:
 print ("Table Exists!")
```

I know its possible to inser user inputed value into a table, but how do I create a table with inputed name? What should go after `CREATE TABLE`? If I use , (TableName,) the code wont compile.
Also, once the new table has been added to database, how do I indicate its name in INSER INTO query?

```
def insert_data():
 conn.execute("INSERT INTO TableName (ID,title,forename,surname)VALUES \
 (234,'Mr','XXX','XXX'")
 conn.commit()
```

Comment: hm?? I clicked as accept, no idea what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for a `CREATE TABLE` statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(column1 datatype1, column2 datatype2, ....)
```

Since you want the user to provide the name of the table, you can do it with string interpolation, because you can't pass it  with a `?` placeholder in the sql query as aparameter:

```
tb_create = f"CREATE TABLE [{TableName}](ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, forename TEXT, surname TEXT)"
```

The table's name must be enclosed inside square brackets, just in case the user provided a name that is not valid (for example it starts with digit or contains spaces).
Also, if you want the column `ID` to be autoincrement, you must use `INTEGER` instead of `INT` for its data type.
Also, there is no `VARCHAR` data type in SQLite. Use `TEXT`.

You can define the variable `TableName` as global so that you can use it in all the functions, like `insert_data()`.
Use  string interpolation for the `INSERT` statement also.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("School")
print ("Database has been created")
TableName = ""

def create_table():
  global TableName
  TableName = input("Enter table name: ").strip()
  tb_exists ="SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = ?"
  if not conn.execute(tb_exists, (TableName,)).fetchone():
    tb_create = f"CREATE TABLE [{TableName}](ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, forename TEXT, surname TEXT)"
    conn.execute(tb_create)
    print("Table created successfully")
  else:
    print("Table Exists!")

def insert_data():
  if len(TableName) > 0:
    conn.execute(f"INSERT INTO [{TableName}] (ID,title,forename,surname) VALUES (234,'Mr','XXX','XXX')")
    conn.commit()

create_table()
insert_data()
```

Comment: thanks, sorry, but what is letter f in  f"CREATE TABLE... ?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the table, or of the columns cannot be parameterized, so you must build the query string. It means that you should control that the entered name is *sane* because building query from strings is know to be a vector for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

But most (if not all) SQL database allow to create a table if it does not already exists. The syntax is just:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name IF NOT EXISTS (
    column_name type,
    ...)
```

So here, you could just do:

```
import re
...
def create_table():
 TableName = input("Enter table name: ")
 # control name:
 if not re.match(r'\w*$', TableName):
     raise IllegalValue("Invalid table name")
 tb_create =f"""CREATE TABLE {TableName} IF NOT EXISTS (ID INT PRIMARY KEY,title VARCHAR(10),
   forename VARCHAR(20), surname VARCHAR(20))"""
 conn.execute(tb_create)
```